# Removing the "foggy screen"/ white overlay from HTML5 <video> elements in Firefox Desktop

Tags: html, css, firefox, dom, video

I have a webpage with several `<video>` elements:

```
<video controls preload="none" poster="/my-video-poster.jpg">
<source src="/my-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I note that on **Chrome** and **IE11** and even on **Firefox Mobile** the `poster` images display at normal brightness (which looks good on the page).

For some inexplicable reason, in **Firefox Desktop** alone, all the (unplayed) video elements look like they are displaying behind a *foggy window*.

I have searched repeatedly and I can find no explanation for this (unwanted) visual effect or how I might remove it (either via CSS or via another approach).

How do I remove this *foggy-window* visual effect?

**Example from Firefox 56:**

[image]

**Example from Chrome 61:**

[image]

Comment: Any screenshots you can show? Also what do you see in the web inspector?

Comment: Screenshots added to question above. Nothing out of the ordinary visible in the web inspector.

Comment: Looking closer this foggy pane effect is only visible when you're looking at the preview image for the video. It goes away upon playing, possibly a bug with your version of Firefox?

Comment: Tested and working on this page (https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/) in Firefox 56 on Ubuntu 16.04.
Fog goes away upon playing.

Comment: To clarify - yes the fog goes away upon playing. But... the fog isn't there even _before_ playing in all the other browsers I mention in the question above.

Comment: I would checkout this entry in the MDN, I didn't read all of it but it's probably the next best step to get rid of the transparent pane. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Video_player_styling_basics

Comment: Thanks. I read through that page (and its prequel) last night - neither mention the _foggy display_ unique to Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `poster`, it comes with the `controls` attribute (*you will see it even if you do not use a poster*).

The only way to remove it is to remove the `controls` attribute and implement custom controls (*through JS*).

---

**Workaround**

Since the problem goes away when the `controls` property is not set, you could start without it, and create a button to start the playing (*like it normally appears*) and when the playing begins then show the controls.

Demo

```js
var videos = document.querySelectorAll('.video-wrap');

[...videos].forEach(function(wrap) {
  wrap.addEventListener('click', function wrapHandler() {
    let video = this.querySelector('video');
    video.addEventListener('play', function playHandler() {
      video.controls = true;
      wrap.classList.add('with-controls');
      video.removeEventListener('play', playHandler);
    })
    video.play();
    wrap.removeEventListener('click', wrapHandler);
  })
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.video-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.video-wrap:before {
  content: "▶";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 99;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding-left: 0.20em;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border: 2px solid currentColor;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px -2px currentColor;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.video-wrap video {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.video-wrap.with-controls:before {
  content: none;
}

.video-wrap.with-controls video {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-wrap">
  <video preload="none" poster="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/640/360/1">
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

(*https://jsfiddle.net/s1t41xn0/2/*)

Comment: Thank you for this - it's very helpful. Are the controls part of the Shadow DOM? Can I restyle the Shadow DOM via javascript?

Comment: Aha. I've found something: `video::media-controls-panel`. I shall investigate further.

Comment: @Rounin i am not optimistic that you will find any solution for firefox, but please post back if you do!

Comment: @Rounin added something like a workaround. (*basically show the controls after the video has started playing, which you must control on your own*)

Comment: I am also not particularly optimistic at this stage. I did think we were beyond the era where browser-makers deployed unstylable chrome... but apparently not.

Comment: Very clever solution, Gaby. I like your well-thought-out work-around very much. Excellent work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Gaby is the definitive answer (without which I would not have been able to develop the solution below), but I wanted to include my eventual production environment solution for the sake of completeness.

**Working Solution:**

```js
var unplayedVideos = document.getElementsByClassName('unplayed');

function initialiseVideo() {
    var videoItem = this;
    var video = videoItem.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    video.play();
    videoItem.classList.remove('unplayed');
    videoItem.removeEventListener('click', initialiseVideo, false);
    setTimeout(function(){video.controls = 'controls';}, 1500);
}

for (let i = 0; i < unplayedVideos.length; i++) {
        unplayedVideos[i].addEventListener('click', initialiseVideo, false);
}
```

```css
.item-video, video {
position: relative;
width: 266px;
height: auto;
}

.item-video h2 {
height: 24px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 24px;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
}

.unplayed::after {
content: '\25b6';
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: calc(50% - 24px + 12px);
left: calc(50% - 36px);
width: 72px;
height: 48px;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 48px;
text-align: center;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
border-radius: 15px;
}

.unplayed:hover::after {
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}

video, .unplayed::after {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-video unplayed">
<h2>Video Title Here</h2>
<video preload="none" poster="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/640/360/1">
<source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
```